# Casting Error when using function in PowerShell defined in C# DLL

Tags: c#, dll, powershell, casting

I'm working on a project to integrate a custom made c# .DLL into powershell. However, I'm having problems
with casting the C# Objects into a form that PowerShell can understand which it cannot. I've searched google
like a million times and tried a few different things but none of them were succesfull.

The following error occurs when I'm calling SNC-getVlan with an array of objects:

**"Exception calling "printObject" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'Objects.blablazzz.DC_Object'"**

I'm posting some small subsets of my code hoping you guys can see what I'm doing wrong.

Classes I'm using:

```
public class DC_Object
{
    public string name = "undefined";
}

public class Cmdb_Host : DC_Object
{
    //Lots of properties
}

public class Cmdb_Vlan : DC_Object
{
    //Lots of properties
}
```

Function that prints the objects:

```
public static void printObject(Object[] objects)
{
    foreach (Object o in objects)
    {
        string name = ((DC_Object)o).name; //I'm assuimg things go wrong in here.
```

The fromJSON function is the function that actually returns the object that is sent into printObject, not sure 
if it matters but I'll post it anyways.

```
static public Object[] fromJSON(string input)
{
    //Check the string to see to what object it should convert to
    switch (input.Substring(0, 16))
    {
        //Reuest for a host (Host Table)
        case "{\"u_cmdb_ci_host":
            if (input[18] == '[') // We have an array
            {
                Container_Host c_host = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container_Host>(input);
                return c_host.u_cmdb_ci_host;
            }
            else    // We have a single object
            {
                Container_Host_Single c_host = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container_Host_Single>(input);
                Container_Host h = new Container_Host();
                h.u_cmdb_ci_host = new Cmdb_Host[1];
                h.u_cmdb_ci_host[0] = c_host.u_cmdb_ci_host;
                return h.u_cmdb_ci_host;
            }
        //Request for a VLAN (Network Table)
        case "{\"cmdb_ci_ip_net":
            Container_Vlan c_vlan = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container_Vlan>(input);
            return c_vlan.cmdb_ci_ip_network;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Powershell Module/Script:

```
#Loads in the custom DLL created for this specific project.
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(“C:\Users\Joey\Documents\PSScripts\DataCollector\DataCollect.dll”)

# Creates a new Client object that handles all communication between the PowerShell module and the
# sncdb-worker at server side.
$client = new-object blablazzz.Sender;
[blablazzz.Config]::Configure("C:\Users\Joey\Documents\PSScripts\DataCollector\asp4all.ini")
$client.Connect();

# This functions returns a Host Machine (Virtual or Physical) in object notation to    for easy post-processing
# in PowerShell. 
Function SNC-GetHost($hostz = "blabla")
{
    return $client.sendMessage([blablazzz.Parser]::getHost($hostz));    
}

# This function returns VLAN information in object notation. This is a collection most     of the time.
function SNC-GetVLAN($vlan = "TLS-TL2-CPH-TEST")
{
    return $client.sendMessage([blablazzz.Parser]::getVlan($vlan));
}
Function printObject($hostz)
{
    [blablazzz.Formatter]::printObject($hostz)
}
```

PowerShell commands (dll is already loaded):

```
PS C:\$variable = SNC-Get-VLAN
PS C:\printObject($variable)
```

I'll have to note that my printDebug function works fine when used on SNC-getHost but doesn't work on
SNC-getVlan, SNC-Get-Vlan returns an array of values while SNC-getHost only returns one value (it's still
in an array though but it doesn't look like PowerShell kept it in an array).

Comment: Just a quick thought...it might help you figure out what's going wrong if you modified your printObject routine to display the type of the object being cast when the cast exception is thrown.

Comment: @David W, I tried printing the object type to the console and came upon something interesting. (Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());) When using this on a Host object it returned SMDB_Host as type and when using it on the Vlan object in powershell it returned a PSObject instead of a SMDB_VLAN object. When I'm using PrintObject($variable[0]) with an index it does print out one instance with the correct SMDB_VLAN type. So I'm assuming it has something to do with me handling objects in PowerShell?

Comment: Sure looks like that to me...

Comment: Try changing the declaration of the argument to printObject from "Object[]" to "DC_Object[]".

Comment: @OldFrat I changed the decleration to DC_Object instead of Object which was the right thing to do anyways. Everything worked just fine after I changed all return paths to DC_Object. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people who might come across the same problem. The solution was to change the return value of my functions and the arguments to DC_Object since this is the top encapsulating object. This solved all casting problems.